# "void does not name a type"

Tags: programming

Hi I'm new at this and can't figure out why I get this error "void does not name a type" on lines 3,5,8,26

```
// _2-5 set Debounce Button
const int BUTTON=2;
const int LED=9;
boolean lastButton = LOW;
boolean currentButton = LOW;
boolean ledOn = false;

Void setup()
{
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (BUTTON, INPUT);
}

boolean debounce(boolean last)

{ 
  boolean current = digitalRead(BUTTON);
  if (last != current)
  {
    delay(5);
    current = digitalRead(BUTTON);
  }
  return current;
}

Void loop()
{
  currentButton = debounce(lastButton);
  if (lastButton == LOW && currentButton == HIGH)
  {
    ledOn = !ledOn;
  } 

  lastButton = currentButton;
  digitalWrite(LED, ledOn);

}
```

Answer (score 7):

I thing the problem is not "void does not name a type", but "Void does not name a type".  Subtle difference:

```
Void setup()
```

should read:

```
void setup()
```

The same on

```
Void loop()
```

should be

```
void loop()
```

Watch those caps - C is case sensitive.